# Draw Transparent Text on NSImage

Tags: swift, macos, swift3, nsstring, nsimage

I'm using the following code to Draw an NSString on an NSImage.How can I make this text transparent

```
text.draw(at:  NSZeroPoint, withAttributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: NSColor.white])
```

How can I make this text transparent?

Please advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NSColor method [withAlphaComponent(_:)](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscolor/) and change its color opacity.

```
text.draw(at: NSZeroPoint, 
          withAttributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font, 
                           NSForegroundColorAttributeName: NSColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)])
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the alpha value of the color, for example

```
text.draw(at:  NSZeroPoint, withAttributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font, 
                                  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: NSColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.3)])
```